# A single word to convey “one who has control of his life/destiny”

Tags: single-word-requests, synonyms

I am looking for a word that describes/conveys one who is in control of his/her life, and believes in his own ability to create his own destiny. I am looking for a word that has some poetic/literature tone/connotation to it. Thank you very much.

Comment: Please add a sample sentence into which the new word would fit.

Comment: self-direction; self-directed

Comment: Perhaps the scarcity of words denoting the notion in question is indicative of man's reluctance to perceive that such _control_ actually exists. IOW, _destiny_ is usually conceived (by whoever does conceive it) as something greater than man: no one really controls it.

Answer (score 1):

"Master" is the closest I can come to one who controls his own destiny with a steady hand.

There are probably several better words without the connotations "master" brings to the table.

"The master worked tirelessly on his tasks, assured they were well conceived"

Answer (score 1):

Maybe **agency**?
Usually I see it used when talking about characters in a story... some have agency, they can impact plot and outcomes. Others that lack agency are there to just fill up the world.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

The word **confident** means sure or self-assured. This word can be used to describe the kind of person you are talking about. The words **powerful** and **strong** can also describe the kind of person you are talking about. But what is most important is that a person is good.

The ability to control the cosmos ("power") is balanced by the idea of virtues ("good qualities"). The four classical virtues are prudence, justice, bravery, and temperance. The Christian faith adds three more virtues to this list: hope, faith, and love.

Comment: What have morality and ethics to do with this?